# EntityFramework always create new relation table record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EntityFramework. My code as below.

**User.cs**

```
public User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> 
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        ToTable("User");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasRequired(x => x.UserRole)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserRoleId);
    }
}
```

**UserRole.cs**

```
public UserRole 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserRole()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class UserRoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleMap()
    {
        ToTable("UserRole");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

**Install.cs**

```
public Install
{
    public static void Install()
    {
        RpUserRoles.Create(new UserRole() { Name = "System" });
        RpUserRoles.Create(new UserRole() { Name = "Admin" });

        var roleSystem = RpUserRoles.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("System")).FirstOrDefault();
        User userSystem = new User();
        userSystem.Name = "UserSystem";
        userSystem.UserRole = roleSystem;
        RpUser.Create(userSystem);

        var roleAdmin = RpUserRoles.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Admin")).FirstOrDefault();
        User userAdmin = new User();
        userAdmin.Name = "UserAdmin";
        userAdmin.UserRoleId = roleAdmin.Id;
        RpUser.Create(userAdmin);
    }
}
```

The result that I get in database is wrong when I create new User in database. The EntityFramework duplicate the records in relationship table. Result as

```
User
| Id | UserRoleId | Name       |
|  1 |          3 | UserSystem |
|  2 |          2 | UserAdmin  |

UserRole
| Id | Name   |
|  1 | System |
|  2 | Admin  |
|  3 | System |
```

The expected UserRoleId for **UserSystem** user should be **1** but I do not know why the EntityFramework will duplicate a new record in UserRole table. As **UserAdmin** set the UserRoleId then should be okay. May I know am I configure wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if you created the UserRole (i.e. `RpUserRoles.Create(new UserRole() { Name = "System" })`) and retrieved it (`RpUserRoles.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("System")).FirstOrDefault()`) from different contexts. Entity Framework will not know that they are the same, so it will treat the second one as if it were new. It looks like you're using a wrapper (RpUserRoles.Create, RpUserRoles.Table) around Entity Framework; how does it handle the context? Does it create one for every method?

Comment: yes, the wrapper is create one for every class. Now i've solved by calling instance context. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be in this way

```
    var roleSystem=RpUserRoles.Create(new UserRole() { Name = "System" });
    var rolAdmin=RpUserRoles.Create(new UserRole() { Name = "Admin" });
    //var roleSystem = RpUserRoles.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("System")).FirstOrDefault();
    User userSystem = new User();
    userSystem.Name = "UserSystem";
    userSystem.UserRole = roleSystem;
    RpUser.Create(userSystem);

    //var roleAdmin = RpUserRoles.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Admin")).FirstOrDefault();
    User userAdmin = new User();
    userAdmin.Name = "UserAdmin";
    userAdmin.UserRoleId = roleAdmin.Id;
    RpUser.Create(userAdmin);
```

the `DbSet<T>.Create` definition is : Creates a new instance of an entity for the type of this set. Note that this instance is NOT added or attached to the set. The instance returned will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy.

so i think you should add also add roleSystem and roleAdmin to the context

hope this will help you